# sshd doesn't show failed login attempts in syslog on CentOS 7

Tags: centos, ssh, rsyslog

after some tinkering with `rsyslog`, `sshd` no longer logs information about failed login attempts to syslog for some reason. I've returned both `sshd` and `rsyslog` configs back to where it was:

```
rpm -V $(rpm -qf /etc/ssh/sshd_config)
rpm -V $(rpm -qf /etc/rsyslog.conf)
```

both produce empty output.

however there is still nothing in `/var/log/secure`, and `journalctl -u sshd` shows only:

```
Oct 02 12:59:29 server04.company.name systemd[1]: Starting OpenSSH server daemon...
Oct 02 12:59:29 server04.company.name systemd[1]: Started OpenSSH server daemon.
```

(in case you're wondering: I made failed login attempt to check this.)

has anyone encountered the same weird behavior?

Answer (score 0):

This happens when you re-create the `/var/log/secure` file. This will break file permissions, especially if SELinux is enabled.

Do the following:

Make sure `/var/log/secure` is owned by `root:root`

```
$ sudo chown root:root /var/log/secure
```

Make sure the permission is set to `600`

```
$ sudo chmod 600 /var/log/secure
```

If SELinux is enabled, you can temporarily disable while troubleshooting your issue

```
$ sudo setenforce 0
```

If you decide to keep SELinux enabled, make sure the file has the following context:

```
$ ls -lZh /var/log/secure
system_u:object_r:var_log_t:s0
```

To manipulate SELinux on the fly (copy context from an existing known working):

```
$ sudo chcon --reference /var/log/dmesg /var/log/secure
```

To manipulate SELinux context permanently, use [semanage](https://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/SELinux) command instead